# Run code if screen has certain width

Tags: javascript, if-statement, width, screen

I'm just trying to write a message in the console when the size of the window is less than 700 px.

The things I have tried is:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 700){
console.log("hello");
}
```

And

```
if(screen.width < 700){
console.log("hello");
}
```

I don't get any error meassages but the code doesn't run. If I ad "px" after the 700 I get the error meassage "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put this inside the `window`'s `resize` event listener. And also you need to use `window.innerWidth` and it always returns an integer value.

```js
if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 760)
      console.log("Less than 760");
    else
      console.log("More than 760");
  });
} else if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 760)
      console.log("Less than 760");
    else
      console.log("More than 760");
  }, true);
} else {
  //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Comment: As a side note, the best approach, depending browser support needed, is to use [window.matchMedia(mediaQueryString)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for the idea... I didn't know that. `:)` I'll have a look at it and update my answer accordingly...

Comment: Im quite new to javascript and havent used stuff like .attachEvemt and . addEventListener. i got my code to work but i gonna have to do some reading on what the code acctually does and why it works. Anyways, Thank you! Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for 'resize' event on 'window':

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

function resize() {

    if (window.innerWidth < 700) {

        console.log('window.innerWidth < 700');
        // window.removeEventListener('resize', resize); // once
    }
}
```

more information about .addEventListener: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: You should provide more information... How is this answer better than mine? Just curious, not blaming... `:)`

Comment: Thank you i got the code to work but i have to read about the first line, i havent used .addEventListener before.

Comment: @PraveenKumar when I writing this answer there is no answer.

Comment: @williamganrot you are right, sorry about that. I thought you can read about "addEventListener" everywhere. This is the right place if you still want to read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @AbdullahAydın Sure... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onResize();
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

function onResize(){
    var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}
```